# Falha ao colocar include em site com wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Eu tenho o endereço de uma web rádio e eu gostaria que ela funcionasse no site Wordpress.
Eu coloquei o código abaixo no meu header.php e essa rádio deve aparecer como navbar no topo de todo o site.

```
<!-- Rádio Web -->
<?php include 'https://player.maxcast.com.br/comunidadedomdedeus';
?>
<!-- Rádio Web -->
```

Print de erro abaixo:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1mag.jpg

Comment: Mas é apenas um link que funciona como navbar, por isso que eu usei include.
Eu não tenho o código todo da navbar.
Claro que eu posso pegar o código fonte mas o resultado é o mesmo.

Comment: Sim, é uma navbar dentro de uma estrutura de página completa, com tags html, head, body, scripts etc...

Comment: Qual a sugestão? iframe?

Comment: Um iframe pode ser uma boa saída e funcionar.

Comment: Eu já tinha tentado com iframe mas não estava muito bom.
Vou tentar novamente.

Comment: Consegui, @Sam.
Quer colocar como resposta?

Comment: Vou formular. Sucesso!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que a origem do include é uma página completa e possui scripts que só irão funcionar na própria página. Um include deve ser uma página apenas com o código necessário e já renderizado.

Você pode usar um iframe, que irá exibir a página de forma independente:

```
<iframe src="https://player.maxcast.com.br/comunidadedomdedeus"></iframe>
```

No CSS você pode definir as propriedades do iframe, como `width`, `height` e `border`:

```
iframe{
   border: none;
   width: 100%;
   height: 60px;
}
```

**Teste:**

```css
iframe{
   border: none;
   width: 100%;
   height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://player.maxcast.com.br/comunidadedomdedeus"></iframe>
```